# Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline : Unable to deserialize the response

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

I am trying to fetch the Data Factory Pipeline Information with the help of following simple command:

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName
```

However, I am getting this Error. I have also update my Az.Data Factory module to the latest one.

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline : Unable to deserialize the response.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Da ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline], SerializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.GetAzureDataFactoryPipelineCommand
```

Please give your valuable suggestions to fix this ?

Comment: Seems to be a [known issue fixed by updating the Az.* module in question](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12099#issuecomment-662911573)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Already updated the latest module of Az. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: This command works for me with the `Az.DataFactory 1.11.0`, please open a new powershell session to try again, also double-check your version via `Get-Module`.

Comment: @JoyWang : Yeah, I have restarted my system and tried in new PS Session. It worked like a charm, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command works for me with the `Az.DataFactory 1.11.0`, please open a new powershell session to try again.